# How to grant dynamodb access to another root account on aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

How to grant dynamodb access to another root account on aws?

My situation: I have a dynamodb filled with some tables created by one root account. This root account is a member of an organization, created by another root account.

The problem: Neither the other root account [organization owner] nor the IAM with Admin permissions created by this root [organization owner] cannot access this dynamodb created by the other root.

Question: Is there a way to grant access to dynamodb from one root to another / to organization created by another root? If so, how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, AWS services owned by one account can be shared with other accounts.
For example it can be done using IAM role. See [this tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html) for details.
Please note that working under root account is against of best practises.